# What is the difference between dispatcher and webserver

Tags: webserver, aem, dispatcher

Is there any difference between dispatcher and webserver?
I was asked this question and I replied both are same. Can anyone pls confirm.
I work for Adobe Experience Manager tool to develop websites.

Answer (score 2):

`Dispatcher` is just a web server plugin - written by Adobe. You can deploy dispatcher in different web servers like `Apache Web Server`, `Microsoft IIS`, `Sun Web Server`.  One of the flexibilities of static web servers is that their features cab be improved and customised by the 3rd party plugins like `Dispatcher`. Check out the features that the `Dispatcher` plugin provides to the static web server [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/dispatcher/using/dispatcher.html).

An HTTP web server provides more robust features - primarily stores, processes and delivers web pages to clients. From Wikipedia -> A web server is a computer system that processes requests via HTTP, the basic network protocol used to distribute information on the World Wide Web. For example, when you go to google.com in your web browser, you're ultimately contacting the web server that hosts this website so that you can communicate with it to request web pages. It provides a whole host of features in terms of performance, protocols and security. This is a very generic explanation. Check out the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server) page for more info.